# Included js/css Files are in script/style tags on Server

Tags: javascript, html, css

On Localhost I see this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="html/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
```

But once uploaded to the server I see this:

```
<style style ="display:none;">... conent of bootstrap.css ... </style>
```

It is the same thing with js-Files. I have absolutely no clue why I am seeing the contents included in tags on the server.

Worst thing is: I am not able to find anything on the internet. I am trying with "css files displayed in style tags instead of files" and all the variations, but the internet doesn't reveal any hint.

I guess it has something to do with the server. Could you give me a hint what I am looking for?

Comment: On which server you deployed?

Comment: Apache. (Is that Info enough?)

Comment: I think you should gather some more information of what u have and use right now, then reformulate your question. With some more info, it's easier to help :)

Comment: What technologies/frameworks you are using.. I think its not problem with the server, unless you have specific settings in your server? If its problem with server you will not get `<style style ="display:none;"> .. </>` this in html.. I hope there is some problem with your plugins or framework etc

Comment: I don't know which informations could be important. A dump of my phpinfo() doesn't seem to make sense. I'll elaborate some more and will get back to this post with more infos. Sounds ok?